# How to represent JSON key identifier to JSON objects dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I would like to write a script that pushes json data but in a key value pair such as

```
[{
   "some id" : {"some data"}
}];
```

so far I have been able to write this

```
const  allProducts= [];
const productsCollection = db.collection('products');
let productsDocument = (await productsCollection.get()) ;

productsDocument.forEach(doc => allProducts.push( { ...doc.id  [{ 
        ...doc.data() }]} ) );;
```

I would want something like this

```
productsDocument.forEach(doc => allProducts.push({ doc.id : { ...doc.data() } }));
```

since the identifier is the document

Comment: Please post what database you use and full code

Comment: firebase firestore, i have updated

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use indexing.

```
productsDocument.map(doc => allProducts[doc['id']] = doc.data));
```

Comment: productsDocument is a firebase array and doesn't have the map function

Comment: If thats the case then you can use forEach instead of map. It will work that way too.